# Permalinks not working Apache + CentOS 7

Tags: permalinks, apache

I have a running CentOS 7 with Apache 2 mariadb stack with vhosts and Let's Encrypt.
I've installed WordPress 4.9.6 on a virtual host using debian style (sites-available -> sites-enabled).

My problem is that I cannot use permalinks. I copy my server configuration below.

```
getenforce 
Disabled
```

`/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Apache configuration file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted 
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Config. file on the public_html directory `/var/www/example.com/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've enable permalinks settings on WordPress admin:

```
https://example.com/%postname%/
```

Permissions of `.htaccess` file are:

-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  235 Jun 24 13:54 .htaccess

`sudo httpd -M` shows:

```
(..)
 rewrite_module (shared)
(..)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the next person, be sure to set AllowOverride All in the correct directory. In Damon's case he set AllowOverride All in the /var/www/html directory, but his site is located in /var/www/example.com/public_html. I could be wrong, but the AllowOverride setting is specific to the directory. Damon should add the AllowOverride All setting to the /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf and /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf files. Without this setting the .htaccess file wordpress uses will work.